# How to retrieve code from database with php ?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to store HTML code in mysql database. If I want to store the following code into database

```
<html>
<body>
<p> this is a paragraph </p
</body>
</html>
```

they store as they are. But when I retrieve them and echo with php the tag get vanished. But I want to echo them as they are above. I also want to store and show not only HTML but other code (c,java,php) also. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: use `htmlentities($whatever)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`htmlentities ()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) php function to echo html codes

```
    $str = "
<html> 
 <body>
     <p> this is a paragraph </p
 </body>
</html>
";


echo htmlentities($str);
```

You can also use     `htmlspecialchars();`

Comment: This is working. Do I do the same if I want to store other code like c or jave. Is there any  problem to store c or java code in database directly? For storing HTML I am using mysql_real_escape_string(). Do I do the same for other code? Or is there any other procedure for storing other code? Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `htmlentities($str)` for that, another nice thing to use is `<pre></pre>`
Putting those tags around the code will preserve newlines, tabs and spaces. In case you want to showcase it.